# Why is "Process finished with exit code 0" being printed when script is run?

Tags: python

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjL8f.jpg)

Somone can tell me why it is print this?

Comment: try running it in the command prompt, it should tell you why it's crashing

Comment: Please add more context, and post the code in a text format. Please also read "how to post a good question"

Comment: That means your code completed without error. Looking at the screenshot, i'm guessing you forgot to call your `main()` function

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  We expect you to look up your issue before posting here.  This message is explained in many places on line.  Therefore, this is not a Stack Overflow issue.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Process finished with exit code 0` this is not an error, it is your IDE that has printed the status and exit code of your script

Comment: what should i do to print the data

Comment: @afik you have to call `main()`, you're currently not running any actual code. Here's how: https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html